# How can I hide large string inside Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

How can large strings (let's say a JSON string with 1 million characters, for example) be stored inside an Excel file hidden?

Currently, I'm storing a JSON string on a cell. My string looks like the one above, but I need to store much info and it must be attached to a Excel file in order to be used within a VBA macro.

> [{"param1=2&param2=4&param3=6&param4=8":1382},{"param1=4&param2=8&param3=12&param4=16":-4840},{"param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4":1168},{"param1=4&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":-4199},{"param1=1&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":-755},{"param1=6&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":1569}

I'd rather avoid an additional file for easier distribution.

Comment: What problem have you run into in trying to do this?

Comment: Currently, I'm storing a JSON string on a cell. My string looks like the one above, but I need to store much info and it must be attached to a Excel file in order to be used within a VBA macro.  [{"param1=2&param2=4&param3=6&param4=8":1382},{"param1=4&param2=8&param3=12&param4=16":-4840},{"param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4":1168},{"param1=4&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":-4199},{"param1=1&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":-755},{"param1=6&param2=8&param3=12&param4=22&param5=1":1569},

Comment: You will need to store it on multiple rows, or you will need to read it directly into a VBA string variable from the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of characters you can store in a single cell. Used to be 250 but is larger now. 32,767 according to [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

There is no way to store more in a single cell. You should use a text file for this instead. Just read the text file from VBA and go from there.

Another option is to use many cells on the worksheet. Then have your macro read all the cells and add them to a single string in VBA. Just like many lines in a book, each cell holds one line. No reason your string has to be stored in a single cell.

I assume you don't want the user to see the JSON code. You could use a hidden worksheet to accomplish that (using many cells).

Comment: Any alternative to a text file?

Comment: Sure there are lots of ways to store stuff but text file would be simplest and fastest in my opinion.

Comment: I need to send the Excel file with the JSON data. So, I don't wan't to always have to copy 2 files. Needing an alternative to text files. Can custom xml be a solution?

Comment: I don't know how to wrap an XML file inside the Excel file. Might be possible although I doubt it; that would be another question. The xlsx file is a zip file. Is it possible to hide a data file inside?